# OpenVPN and Performance

Tags: networking, security, vpn, performance, openvpn

From my understanding RDP is encrypted and so is the OpenVPN connection so that is an encryption in an encryption.

My Setup:

```
LAPTOP <---> REMOTE SERVER <---> OFFICE SYSTEM
```

Due to firewalls I setup OpenVPN on SSL 443 to get out to my home systems by connecting them all to a remote openvpn server. However, the connection is very laggy and I am assuming this is due to the double encryption. Can I disabled the OpenVPN encryption some way to maybe improve performance?

Comment: This question will probably be closed soon as not constructive, too vague and others -- you provide nothing that can be used to formulate a useful answer, not even your OpenVPN server and client configuration. But no, the problem is very probably not the "double encryption", unless your laptop and remote office servers run on CPUs from the last century. Much more probable candidates are your network connections, both in bandwidth and network latency, and your OpenVPN configuration settings.

Comment: The chance that this has anything to do with encryption is almost zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the actual question: you can disable encryption in OpenVPN with these configuration directives:

```
auth none
cipher none
```

Set these in your server configuration and you will have no security at all provided by OpenVPN. Obviously this is ludicrous and not at all recommended.

See for example: http://docs.openvpn.net/under-the-hood/change-encryption-cipher-in-access-server/